# Load the first item after the first item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to implement the recyclerview with functionality as to display the first item after last like circle

Comment: Put what you have done so far.

Comment: when returning count, return `MAX_INT` for example. When setting up the view, take the `position % count` index of source list.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you to try following changes in your adapter class. Set getItemCount to return a very large value like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Then to get the actual item position need a modulus operation

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActionItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    position = position % SIZE_OF_LIST;
};
```